# PHP generate JSON in certain format

Tags: php, arrays, json

So i want to generate my JSON for a angular app in this format. The result will be used for a dropdown and i need it to be in this particular format

```
[
{
  id:1,
  post_title:title1},
{
  id:2,
  post_title:title1},
{
  id:3,
  post_title:title3},
and so on ...
]
```

But when i send my JSON back to my angular app it looks like this

```
{
"0": {
    "id": "1",
    "post_title": "Batman Ipsum"
},
"1": {
    "id": "2",
    "post_title": "Title fit for a (precariously enthroned) king"
},
"2": {
    "id": "3",
    "post_title": "Cupcake Ipsum"
},
"3": {
    "id": "4",
    "post_title": "The most presidential lorem ipsum in history."
},
"4": {
    "id": "5",
    "post_title": "Quote Ipsum"
},
"5": {
    "id": "6",
    "post_title": "Yet another Batman Ipsum"
},
"6": {
    "id": "9",
    "post_title": "Yet another Harry Potter ipsum"
},
"7": {
    "id": "10",
    "post_title": "Vegetable Ipsum"
}
}
```

How to change it to the format that i want?

My `php` code

```
function fetchPagesNames()
{
$response = array();
$resultArray=array();
try {
    $sql = "SELECT id,post_title FROM posts";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error() . $sql);
    $resultCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCount > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultArray[]=$row;
        }
        $response['status'] = 'Success';
        $response['message'] = "Post's Obtained";
        $response['results'] = $resultArray;
    } else {
        $response['status'] = 'Error';
        $response['message'] = 'No Pages in the Database';
        die();
    }
    echo json_encode($response,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
} catch (exception $e) {
    $response['status'] = 'Error';
    $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
}
```

What changes are needed?

Comment: why not to convert that into `object` using `$.parseJSON(resp);` and after that `loop` the `object` to populate `drop down`

Comment: what is your PHP version? Is there a reason why you used `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`? Finally, JSONs (objects) should start with the `{`, and JSON (arrays) should start with `[`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major differences between your "required" format and the output you're getting:

1. The format you've quoted as being required is not actually valid JSON because you're missing the quotes.
   The JSON format is very explicit in that it must have quotes around property names and string values. The JSON you're getting outputted is correct in this regard.
2. Your required output has an outer layer that is an array, whereas your actual output has an object, with numbered elements as strings.
   The reason for this is because you're using `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` in your call to `json_encode()`. This argument forces all parts of the JSON otput to be processed as objects not arrays. Remove this and you'll get the top-level array that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` from `json_encode()`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: @Vincent - no. This was a trivial bug in his code. Repeating the code minus the `FORCE` flag wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode` for print object.

or look like this...

```
try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tekst";
    $result = $dao->conn->query($sql);
    //$resultCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resultArray[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode(
                $resultArray
                    );
    } else {
        $response['status'] = 'Error';
        $response['message'] = 'No Pages in the Database';
        die();
    }
} catch (exception $e) {
    $response['status'] = 'Error';
    $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```